# Getting probabilities of best model for RandomizedSearchCV

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, grid-search

I'm using `RandomizedSearchCV` to get the best parameters with a 10-fold cross-validation and 100 iterations. This works well. But now I would like to also get the probabilities of each predicted test data point (like `predict_proba`) from the best performing model.

How can this be done?

I see two options. First, perhaps it is possible to get these probabilities directly from the `RandomizedSearchCV` or second, getting the best parameters from `RandomizedSearchCV` and then doing again a 10-fold cross-validation (with the same seed so that I get the same splits) with this best parameters.

Edit: Is the following code correct to get the probabilities of the best performing model? X is the training data and y are the labels and model is my `RandomizedSearchCV` containing a `Pipeline` with imputing missing values, standardization and SVM.

```
cv_outer = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True, random_state=0)
y_prob = np.empty([y.size, nrClasses]) * np.nan
best_model = model.fit(X, y).best_estimator_

for train, test in cv_outer.split(X, y):
    probas_ = best_model.fit(X[train], y[train]).predict_proba(X[test])
    y_prob[test] = probas_
```

Comment: RandomizedSearchCV does have a `predict_proba()` which will access the fitted model with the best params. Is that what you want? Or do you want to have the predictions for each value in test fold?

Comment: @VivekKumar I have done an update to my question. Do you think that will work?

Comment: Please add how you defined the `model` and how are you using the  `cv_outer`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood it right, you would like to get the individual scores of every sample in your test split for the case with the highest CV score. If that is the case, you have to use one of those CV generators which give you control over split indices, such as those here: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/statistical_inference/model_selection.html#cross-validation-generators

If you want to calculate scores of a new test sample with the best performing model, the `predict_proba()` function of `RandomizedSearchCV` would suffice, given that your underlying model supports it.

Example:

```
import numpy
skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, random_state=0, shuffle=True)
scores = cross_val_score(svc, X, y, cv=skf, n_jobs=-1)
max_score_split = numpy.argmax(scores)
```

Now that you know that your best model happens at `max_score_split`, you can get that split yourself and fit your model with it.

```
train_indices, test_indices = k_fold.split(X)[max_score_split]
X_train = X[train_indices]
y_train = y[train_indices]
X_test = X[test_indices]
y_test = y[test_indices]
model.fit(X_train, y_train) # this is your model object that should have been created before
```

And finally get your predictions by:

```
model.predict_proba(X_test)
```

I haven't tested the code myself but should work with minor modifications.

Comment: Your understanding is correct, thanks for your answer. But I'm still confused. Of course I can get the best performing model from RandomizedSearchCV  by using best_estimator_ and then I could do again a cross-validation and using predict_proba() on this best model but in this cross-validation I should then train the model again just with the best parameters and not using just the best model.

Comment: I have done an update to my question which makes it clearer what I mean

Comment: I updated my answer, please let me know if it works.

Comment: I think that is not what I want, please see my code in the question. Your code searches the split with the best score but what I want is the model with the best score over all splits, i.e. the best parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You need to look in `cv_results_` this will give you the scores, and mean scores for all of your folds, along with a mean, fitting time etc...

If you want to `predict_proba()` for each of the iterations, the way to do this would be to loop through the params given in `cv_results_`, re-fit the model for each of then, then predict the probabilities, as the individual models are not cached anywhere, as far as I know.

`best_params_` will give you the best fit parameters, for if you want to train a model just using the best parameters next time.

See `cv_results_` in the information page http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.RandomizedSearchCV.html

Comment: Or could I just call fit() again on best_estimator_ in a cross-validation?

Comment: That should be possible, or you could just call `predict_proba()` on the `best_estimator_`?

Comment: I have done an update in my question which makes it clearer what I mean. Do you think this code will work?

Comment: Looking at your code, that seems like a good way to go about it, but I am unsure if the actual data splits will be the same as the ones you get from calling `StratifiedKFold` later. One way to validate would be to see if the train/test scores match those in `cv_results_`

Comment: But when I set in RandomizedSearchCV cv=cv_outer then the splits should be the same because I have set  random_state=0 in cv_outer, or am I wrong?